# kivy Calendar: How to insert kivy Calendar in a BoxLayout and set a function in its buttons

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

[edited]I am new to kivy and I would like to ask if it is possible to contain the Calendar in a BoxLayout alongside with other BoxLayouts that will display the input of the selected button of the calendar. I tried to add it as a widget but unfortunately it throws this error

```
 File "C:\Python27\coffee.py", line 572, in calendar
 self.calendar.add_widget(self.cal)
 AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'add_widget'
```

I would like to add an on_release attribute(if possible) to the buttons present in the calendar as they are clicked e.g(Button 1 -> redirect to another screen or display it's text to the other BoxLayout)
here is the python file:

```
class Reservation(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Reservation, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        calen = ObjectProperty()
        self.calendar()
    def calendar(self):
        self.cal = CalendarWidget()
        self.calen.add_widget(self.cal)
```

and here is where it will be added:

```
<Reservation>:
     name: "Reserve"
     calen: Cal
     BoxLayout:
         BoxLayout: 
             id: Cal
         BoxLayout: 
             id: output_box
             orientation: 'vertical'
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: It is bad programming practice to call a method and have an attribute with the same name, for example a first step is to change the name of the function calendar().

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry about that. I am still a beginner in OOP and I still want to learn so much more and know some practices that i may need to know. Thank you for your advice and as well as taking the effort to remind us beginners of the practices we need to know especially concerning the common mistakes we omit.

Comment: see my answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I indicated in my comments, it is bad programming practice to call a variable and a function with the same name since it can hide other properties

Going to the point, `calendar = ObjectProperty()` is not linked to anything that Calendar does not link to the `BoxLayout`, it is also a local variable that its life cycle ends when the constructor is finished. In your case when you use `self.calendar.add_widget(self.cal)` the self.calendar refers to the calendar method where you call it and clearly the name of a method is not a widget causing that error.

What you must do is the `ObjectProperty` be a property of the class, and assign it in the .kv, in addition to changing the name of the function:

You must use clock to access the widget because the children are not yet established in the construct. In the case of the `Clock` schedule_once this will be called a frame afterwards so it will already have the children.

***.py**

```
from kivy.clock import Clock

...

class Reservation(Screen):
    calendar = ObjectProperty()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Reservation, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda *args: self.create_calendar())

    def create_calendar(self):
        self.cal = CalendarWidget()
        self.calendar.add_widget(self.cal)
```

***.kv**

```
<Reservation>:
     name: "Reserve"
     calendar: calendar # set value to ObjectProperty
     BoxLayout:
         BoxLayout: 
             id: calendar
         BoxLayout: 
             id: output_box
             orientation: 'vertical'
```

Comment: I would like to clarify if it is possible to assign an on_release button to the calendar and if i were to do it would i add it in the          
                                                              
             self.calendar.add_widget(self.cal) in order for me to add some actions to it?

Comment: @Iwanttoknow 
That is another question, if my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, review the [tour], that is the best way to thank. Create another question and I will be happy to follow you helping.

Comment: I would like to clarify if the ObjectProperty is not needed even in assigning TextInputs and other stuff alike if it is assigned in the kv file and also if it is possible to assign an on_release button to the calendar and if i were to do it would i add it in the          
                                                              
             self.calendar.add_widget(self.cal) in order for me to add some actions to it?

Comment: It is not really necessary to create the ObjectProperty in the .py, kivy will create them if you see it necessary in the .kv.